# Is there a way to /testfor a specific potion?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am working on a map with a boss fight where a witch is the boss. During the boss fight, I need different mobs to spawn on the ground based on which potion the witch threw (slowness, poison, weakness, or damage).

Using the testfor command, I have tried:
/testfor @e[type=ThrownPotion] {Potion:{id:potion,Damage:16388}}
and I have connected a comparator output from the command block. Yes, the command block is on a clock.

When I throw the Poison Splash Potion (0:33), the command block says the potion did not have the required data structure.

Is there something wrong with the command? Is there something wrong with the ThrownPotion? Is there a possible way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Irrevelant: Wow! I remember you, TBNRfrags played your map!

Comment: @PanV can you send me a link to the video where he played my map? I cannot seem to locate it and I would appreciate it very much. You can send it to me on my YT or just reply to this comment. Thanks!

Comment: Sowy, I cannot do that... ;.; I don't remember. I just heard about you, I didn't see it in a vid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When testing for pre-existing data, you must declare the data as-is. The item ID is *saved* with a namespace, defaulting to `minecraft`, but your input via /testfor (or /scoreboard) will not be automatically corrected. As such, you must input the namespace that the item is saved with, becoming `minecraft:potion`.

The `Damage` tag is saved with a tag-type of Short. In order to declare a Short, you must append the numerical value with an 's'.

Your command will become:

```
/testfor @e[type=ThrownPotion] {Potion:{id:"minecraft:potion",Damage:16388s}}
```

Comment: Thanks Skylinerw! I can't believe it was that simple. Btw I was already subscribed to your YT before I asked this question